# Python GUI to remplace some contents in a word document using( importing ) data from an excel file

Tags: python, excel, database, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a python GUI.
Its concept is to import two files : a word document ( the one which will be edited later ), and an excel file.

firstly to import an excel file and here an exemple of its content :

[excel database][1]

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtypN.png
```

secondly to import the word document (.docx) and analyze its content and detect any " Pllexxx" ( xxx are integers ) in it which are located in tables, here is an exemple :

[word document content][2]

```
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Cze.png
```

thirdly to remplace any Pllexxx in the tables with REQyyy and download the new word document file.

here is an exemple : Plle112 to be replaced by REQ5592 using the database from excel

here is my code which doesn't work and I don't understand where is the error :

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from pandastable import Table
from tkintertable import TableCanvas
from docx import Document



root = Tk()

message_label = Label(root,
                      text='my name',
                      font=('Arial', 19, 'underline'),
                      fg='Green')
message_label2 = Label(
    text='Modify word file',
    font=('Arial', 14, 'underline'),
    fg='Red')

select_button = Button(root,
                       text='Select',
                       font=('Arial', 14),
                       bg='Orange',
                       fg='Black',
                       command=lambda: select_excel_file())

convert_button = Button(root,
                        text='Convert',
                        font=('Arial', 14),
                        bg='Orange',
                        fg='Black',
                        command=lambda: convert_word())

exit_button = Button(root,
                     text='Exit',
                     font=('Arial', 14),
                     bg='Red',
                     fg='Black',
                     command=root.destroy)


message_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
message_label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
select_button.grid(row=3, column=0,
                   padx=0, pady=15)
convert_button.grid(row=3, column=1,
                    padx=0, pady=15)
exit_button.grid(row=3, column=2,
                 padx=10, pady=15)


def select_excel_file():
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',
                                           title='Select a excel file',
                                           filetypes=(('excel file', '*.xls')
                                                      , ('excel file', '*.xlsx'),
                                                      ('excel file', '*.xls')))

    my_dic = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col=0).to_dict()

def convert_word():
    file1_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',
                                            title='Select a word file',
                                            filetypes=(('docx file', '*.docx'),
                                                       ('docx file', '*.docx')))

    document = Document(file1_name)

    for table in document.tables:
        for cell in table.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if 'Plle' in paragraph.text:
                    m = ''
                    for j in paragraph.text:
                        if j.isdigit():
                            m += str(j)
                    paragraph.text = 'REQ' + str(my_dic['REQ'][int(m)])



    document.save('new word file.docx')


root.title('modification of word files')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.mainloop()
```

here is an exemple of the output ( the changements that I am seeking ) :

[enter image description here][3]

```
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCSpz.png
```

please help me detect the errors and fix my code !

Comment: it "does not work" covers a lot of ground. What specific problem are you having firstly?

Comment: my main problem is how to create a fonction which remplaces every PlleXXX located and the tables on the word document by the REQYYY ( importing the data from excel ) @PaulCollingwood

Comment: does the code that finds the locations of PlleXXX work?

Comment: I tried to compile that code separately and it worked but it didn't cover all the PlleXXX, it's like taking the first Plle 112 and the second Plle13  and change them correctly but all the other one took also their results. @PaulCollingwood

Comment: it might help if you write some tests: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/ to keep the working parts working while you work on the rest of it